# android expandable list view get group from child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a button in a child, and I want to change a group's TextView of this child.
In my getChildView I got.

```
    holderChild.revert = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.revert);
    holderChild.revert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ViewHolderChild v2 = (ViewHolderChild)((View)v.getParent()).getTag();

        }
    });
```

And with this I have the child, but I'd want to have the group of this child

Comment: ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html

Comment: I class extends to BaseExpandableListAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html

However, this is a sample code:

```
// Listview on child click listener
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                    + " : "
                    + listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    return false;
}
});
```

I hope its useful for you.

Comment: No, because when I click in mi imageView, it goes to onClick where I only have the parameter View v